# Count and print letters by their repetition

Tags: java

I have this problem to do:
Read a word composed only by small character and print them on screen starting from the most repeated letter from the less, if two letters have the same repetition time print the smallest value first. It has to be done in the smallest time, so they suggested me to use bufferedread and bufferedwrite. EX:

**Input word:**

```
intensified
```

**Output word:**

```
iiieenndfst
```

I tried this first:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
    String word = br.readLine();
    int[] f = new int[26];
    int maxcont = 0;
    StringBuilder rez = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        int cont = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < word.length(); j++){
            if(word.charAt(i) == word.charAt(j) && word.codePointAt(i) > 96) {
                f[word.codePointAt(i)-97]++;
                cont++;
            }
        }
        word = word.replace(word.charAt(i), 'O');
        if (maxcont < cont)
            maxcont = cont;
    }
    while(maxcont != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
            if (f[i] == maxcont) {
                for (int j = maxcont; j > 0; j--) {
                    rez.appendCodePoint(i+97);
                }
            }
        }
        maxcont--;
    }
    bw.write(String.valueOf(rez));
    bw.flush();

}
```

And it says that it takes too much time, so I tried this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
    String word = br.readLine();
    int[] f = new int[123];
    int maxcont = 0, min = 122, max = 96;
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        int cont = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < word.length(); j++){
            if(word.charAt(i) == word.charAt(j) && word.codePointAt(i) > 96) {
                f[word.codePointAt(i)]++;
                cont++;
            }
        }
        if (word.codePointAt(i) < min && word.codePointAt(i) > 96)
            min = word.codePointAt(i);
        if (word.codePointAt(i) > max)
            max = word.codePointAt(i);
        word = word.replace(word.charAt(i), 'O');
        if (maxcont < cont)
            maxcont = cont;
    }
    while(maxcont != 0) {
        for (int i = min; i <= max; i++) {
            if (f[i] == maxcont) {
                for (int j = maxcont; j > 0; j--) {
                    bw.write((char) i);
                    bw.flush();
                }
            }
        }
        maxcont--;
    }
}
```

and I have the same time problem, so in which way can I improve my code in order to make it faster??

Comment: How much time should it take and where are your printing out the results in your code?

Comment: I don't really know how much time, I just know it has to be faster

Answer (score 1):

Your program logic is ok. The reason the program is hanging is because BufferedReader will hang when a demand is made for data but the input buffer is empty. You are trying to read user input from System.in but haven't, initialize by writing out a message to the user requesting input:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
System.out.println("Enter the word to be evaluated:"); //Add this line
String word = br.readLine();
```

Comment: The program it's run by a compiler like ideone, so it works if I leave it without that line, but I just have to do it faster